# Replacing a mongo doc when a condition is met using mongo java driver 3.0+

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a requirement in which multiple clients are concurrently writing to a MongoDB. Each Mongo doc is having a custom `version` field. Also I have to ensure that old doc does not overwrite a new doc. Each write completely replaces a mongo doc.

My Replace document code looks something like below:- (in the example below `version` let'say can be obtained by `doc.getVersion()`) :-

```
MongoCollection<Document> productCollection = mongoDb.getCollection("test");    
List<WriteModel<Document>> writes = new ArrayList<WriteModel<Document>>();
            for (MongoInputDoc doc : docCollection) {
                UpdateOptions updateOptions = new UpdateOptions();
                updateOptions.upsert(true);
                writes.add(new ReplaceOneModel<Document>(new Document(doc.getIdName(), new BsonString(doc.getIdValue())),
                        doc.getDoc(), updateOptions));
            }

            try {
                if (writes.size() > 0) {
                    productCollection.bulkWrite(writes);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println(e.getMessage())
            }
```

Can some one let me know how can I add the version check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query worked for me:-

```
Document query = new Document("$and", Arrays.asList(new Document(
            doc.getIdName(), new BsonString(doc.getIdValue())),
            new Document("doc_version", new Document("$lt",
                doc.getVersion()))));
        writes.add(new ReplaceOneModel<Document>(query, doc.getDoc(),
            updateOptions));
```

Then while doing the bulkWrite catching `MongoBulkWriteException` and igonoring error code `11000` & `11001`